# Connect to SQL Server using Windows impersonation

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service, impersonation

I wrote a windows service in C# and I have to use windows authentication to SQL server. So I am using Trusted Connection in the SQL connection string.

Here's the set up:
Windows service has WCF hosted with in it.
Windows service uses local service account which is admin on that application server... Because the WCF has to register the uri.
So I impersonate another account which will use Windows auth to SQL server... I am not given a SQL account.. So the problem is when I try to auth after impersonation... It's trying to use the account under which the service is running even though I check windows identity and it's correct and is the impersonated account.Why is it using the service account?

Another question is, one of the methods of the WCF service returns a list of all exceptions... This list works when it is empty or if I put a new exception in it but if the Windows service threw the exception and that exception goes into the list and I try to retrieve it it says no end point. Any ideas? It isn't timing out or anything bc I increased the times. I have other methods that just return strings and they work fine.

Comment: You only need to do the HTTP URL reservation once, when you install your service. After that, the service can run using any account you like. And I think that's a better option than manually storing and decrypting a password for impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out after more debugging. The impersonation was working fine but my decrypted password wasn't correct. So fixed that.

The question about the list of exceptions not being retrieved... Apparently .Net couldn't serialized the exception class. So I wrote a custome class that returns exception info and it works great.